# Python Pandas: How can I drop rows using df.drop and df.loc?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'user': ['Adam', 'Barry', 'Cindy', 'Dirk', 'Ella'],
        'income': [50000, 0, 100000, 30000, 0],
        'net worth': [250000, 1000000, 2000000, 50000, 0]
    }
)
```

[image]

So far, I've been removing rows based on conditions using the following:

```
df2 = df[df.income != 0]
```

[image]

And using multiple conditions like so:

```
df3 = df[(df['income'] != 0) & (df['net worth'] > 100000)]
```

[image]

Question: Is this the preferred way to drop rows? If not, what is? Is it possible to do this via `df.drop` and `df.loc`? What would the syntax be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.loc` creates a subset of the rows you want to keep rather than `.drop` filter rows you want to remove. `drop` need the row label (index name).

The equivalent of your last filter with `drop` is:

```
>>> df.drop(df[~((df['income'] != 0) & (df['net worth'] > 100000))].index)

    user  income  net worth
0   Adam   50000     250000
2  Cindy  100000    2000000

# OR a bit smart:
>>> df.drop(df[(df['income'] == 0) | (df['net worth'] <= 100000)].index)

    user  income  net worth
0   Adam   50000     250000
2  Cindy  100000    2000000
```

Which syntax do you prefer?

Comment: Well, when you put it like that, I suppose the original syntax is simpler :-) However, it was good to know how I could use `.drop` and `.loc`. Thanks!